# 100Mbit vs 1Gb/sec transferring 10MB file...speed difference?

Tags: network, speed, performance

Two PC's A and B speed of transfer bits across the wire...

100/Mbit Link  (100,000,000 bits)

1Gb/s Link (1,000,000,000 bits)

File Size:  10MB    (80,000,000 bits)

I'm trying to figure out if we have TWO PC's  (A)  and (B) with a 100Mb/sec Link and we copy a 10MB file from PC-A to PC-B at 100Mbits-to-->100Mbits  will the bits transfer from PC-A to PC-B at the same speed as if we are on a 1Gb link or will there be a difference and why (i.e. is it serialization, ?).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking... Obviously if one PC can only handle 100Mbit, then the other one will have to slow down to match. The 100Mbit interface cannot magically start accepting data 10 times faster than it is physically capable of. Now, this doesn't mean that the 1Gbit interface will downgrade - the magic will happen at the switch which will accept packets quickly from one interface and then send them slowly to the other. When its internal buffer is full though, it will also signal the faster interface to take a break until there's room again to continue.

Comment: Alternatively, if you've connected both computers directly with a cable (and no switch between), then the 1Gbit interface will work in 100Mbit mode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bandwidth is how fast an interface serializes bits onto the wire. Obviously, a 1 Gbps interface serializes bits 10 times faster than a 100 Mbps interface. With everything else equal, a 1 Gbps connection will transfer a file 10 times as fast as a 100 Mbps connection.

In reality, there are other factors involved, including whether or not host resources can handle the full 1 Gbps connection. When 1 Gbps ethernet interfaces were first introduced, the host bus could only handle 400 Mbps, so it could not take advantage of the full 1 Gbps connection. That was a long time ago, and most modern hosts have a bus speed that can do the full 1 Gbps.

There are other factors that affect the performance of a file transfer, including latency, upper-layer protocols, buffers, processor speed, and how loaded the host is.

Comment: Thank you ....Is there a standard table that shows what the Serialization is based on speed 10, 100, 1000 and also is the serialization including the Frame header or just data payload i.e 1538 or is it 1500

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The bandwidth is the serialization rate. Depending on the protocol, you could have some overhead. For example, ethernet has a seven-octet preamble, one-octet Start-of-Frame Delimiter, 14-octet frame header, variable up to 1500-octet frame payload, four-octet Frame Check Sequence, and a 12-octet inter-packet gap that all consume bandwidth, but other protocols, such as those using a serial interface (HDLC, PPP, etc.) do not have all of that because much can be handled by control wires that ethernet does not have.

Comment: I was looking up a table for serialization delay based on Link Speed and Packet Size.  An example is for 1500 byte packet with 10Mb/s link takes (1.2ms), at 100Mb/s it takes (120) microseconds and at 1Gb/s it takes (1.2) microseconds.   Does that seem right?  and if it does, does that Ethernet size include headers+payload, how are these measurements taken is it with or without headers OR does it not matter.

Comment: I explained the ethernet overhead. All the parts use bandwidth. Ethernet has a frame overhead of 38 octets of bandwidth, exclusive of the frame payload of up to 1500 octets. The overhead is regardless of the bandwidth. Every frame will have the overhead. Also, remember that not all frames will have a 1500 octet payload. There are various reasons for smaller payloads, even when transferring a large file. File transfers normally use TCP, and you will need to take into account things like acknowledgements, resends, etc.

Comment: You may also want to take into account jumbo frames. And In TCP, you'll also need to take into account window size.

Comment: @user1532080, my answer is, "_With everything else equal, a 1 Gbps connection will transfer a file 10 times as fast as a 100 Mbps connection._" I was only giving an example that there are other factors involved, and the table really does not exist. I was not going to go into any detail for all the various protocols involved, of which ethernet is only one data-link protocol and TCP is only one transport protocol. There are far too many protocols with various factors and combinations to create a table for other than academic reasons (off-topic here).

Comment: @JoelP You are overthinking this; it's just simple maths. The time to put 1500 bytes onto the wire for 10Mb Ethernet is 1500 * 8 / 10E6/s = 1.2 ms. In real life there are other things like protocol overheads and propogation delays to think about also.

Answer (score 2):

There are a very large number of variables, in terms of the internals of the PC at each end, the software used to control the transfer, and the lower level protocols used.

Achieving a reliable transfer also means both ends keeping check of where they got to, and a delay while they agree how far they have got, before they carry on sending. This means there are inevitable overheads to consider, (bits that must be sent back and forth in addition to the data bits of the payload) which consume some of the bandwidth, AND introduce elements of Latency (the time taken for a message to pass from one end to the other, and a confirmation to return to the sender). All of these factors combine, and mean that the data will flow at a rate that is less than the available bandwidth (and often a lot less, when the Bandwidth is large).

Then some software can use compression (recognising chunks that are similar to previous chunks) so that it can send a small reference to the previous chunk, rather than repeating the chunk again).

So the speed at which data can be moved from end to end, is usually a lot less than the Bandwidth (particularly when the Bandwidth is large), but can sometimes be much faster than would be expected (as is increasingly useful when the bandwidth is small).

The choice of Protocol, and the higher level software choices, can make a very significant difference in the speed achieved, but are highly dependent on the specific situation. The unique blend of processing power / memory buffers / Bandwidth / Latency / Numbers and Sizes of files / Compressibility of data that occurs in a particular case.

But to answer the specific question. Given data to be moved between the same devices, over the same network (just running at different speed), the 1Gbps Network is passing bits 10 times faster than a 100Mbps Network and will likely be quicker end to end.

BUT because of the contribution from Overheads, and the speed limitations within the PC at each end, it won't be 10 times faster, and if there are issues with equipment or cabling that cause lots of errors and retries at the higher speed, it is possible that the end to end speed is worse.

Comment: Gigabit speed all through is no rocket science any more. Decent HDDs have exceeded that speed for more than a decade. SSDs and main memory run circles around it.